# RNG and Mersenne twister learning resources for the amateur

Tags: random-number-generator, pseudo-random-generator

I am a complete amateur in the area of random number generators. I would appreciate resources to begin learning.

Also I would also like to learn about Mersenne twister. Resources that are easy on the math side of these things would be more appreciated.

N.B: I have some programming experiences. I code in Python and JavaScript